# Can't connect to SignalR server from Xamarin.Forms app

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, signalr

Here's my environment:

- Visual Studio 2017 15.1, running on Windows 10, which runs in VM on MacOSX.
- In VS I installed API23 Android SDK.
- On MacOSX: Xamarin Studio 6.3
- Both, XS on Mac and VS on Windows have Xamarin.iOS 10.8.0.175

I have one solution where I implemented signalR server. It's a simple chat server. It works. It's running on the windows VM. I tried connecting and sending message from my mac (so technically a separate computer in the network) and it works!

Now, I'm trying to consume it from Xamarin.Forms iOS and Droid projects.. without any success. In `PCL`'s App class I have:

```
    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
        try
        {
            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("10.0.1.58:49919");
            var chatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");

            hubConnection.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.

        }
    }
```

> System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Worth a try with a `http://` prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a http:// prefix and another thing to try is to end a trailing slash.

So try combinations of:

`new HubConnection("http://10.0.1.58:49919");`

`new HubConnection("http://10.0.1.58:49919/");`

`new HubConnection("10.0.1.58:49919/");`